# Parameter Passing with in URL

Tags: java, jersey

Have a question about passing number of values in url.
 I get HTTP status 405 method not allowed.. How can i pass all those variables    to this method ? Any help appreciated..

```
@POST
@Path("/{message}/{messager_name}/{messager_last_name}/{messager_id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addMessage(@PathParam("message") String message, @PathParam("messager_name")String messager_name, @PathParam("messager_last_name")String messager_last_name ,@PathParam("messager_id") long messager_id){

    new MessageService().addMessage(message, messager_name, messager_last_name, messager_id);
}
```

Comment: Are you simply typing the URL into a browser? If so, that would be a GET request, hence the 405. You will have to test this with a POST request. This can be done in code, or with a simple REST client browser extension.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will try it!

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna to send the parameters via the URL, i think you should change the  @POST to @GET.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, though it could be edited to be an acceptable answer.